# Automatically return jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, when I call:

```
$("selector").a_function(function(){
    this.toggleClass("a-class");
}
```

I am told that `this` is of a certain type, and does not have the jQuery function available to it. The problem is that I am not getting jQuery objects returned to me. The way I am getting around this is to do:

```
jquery_object = jQuery(this);
```

every time. I thought that `$()` is equivalent to calling `jQuery` and that I am supposed to receive a jQuery object.

Is this normal? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That is jQuery default setting, if u want jQuery Object you have to get $(this)

Comment: `this` is the DOM element that the jQuery object represents

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `$(this)` instead of just `this`.

In the case you gave `this` doesn't refer to the DOM element.

By wrapping it in the standard JQuery selector function, you'll actually be calling to the DOM element.

I use this a lot for click handlers.

`$('a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('a-class');
});`

Pretty much any function in JQuery that gets called through a selector and has a callback will use this format.